# Inorder successor in BST

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

Given a function getInorderSuccessor which takes a BST (Binary Search Tree) as it's parameter. Every node has an extra pointer "next" , which is intialized to null, fill next with node pointers which represent Inorder Successor. my following code is not giving correct output

```
node * getInorderSuccessor(node * root){
struct node * current = root;
static int flag = 0;

if (root != NULL)
{
if (flag != 2)
{ 
    current->next = getInorderSuccessor(current->left);
}
    if(current ==root)
        flag = 1;
    if (flag == 1)
    {
        flag = 2;
        current->next = root;
        }
    if (flag!=2)
    {

        current->next = getInorderSuccessor(current->right);

    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "left" to be high and "right" to be low:

If there is a `left` branch, the next higher node will be in it.  So the successor will be the lowest (rightmost) node in the `left` branch.

If there isn't a `left` branch, we need to go up the tree (towards the root) until the next node up is left of the current node, i.e. until the current node (as we go up the tree) is the `right` branch of its parent.  That parent will be the successor.

In any case, you need some way of knowing what each node's parent is, at least on the path to the current node... since you may need to move toward the root of the tree.  This could be a `parent` pointer in each node, or some sort of list of nodes on the path to the current one.

As for the code you have, I'm not sure how you meant it to work, but:

```
current->next = getInorderSuccessor(current->left);
```

...looks strange.  If `current->left` is the high branch, then `current->left`'s successor would be at least two nodes up from `current` -- so it couldn't be `current`'s immediate successor.  If `left` is the low branch, it can't contain `current`'s successor at all, so it still doesn't make sense.

I also don't see a `return` statement anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The same static variable is used by all the (recursive) invocations of the function. If you want to remember the path where you left off, you'll need more (or other) variables.